# Unverified apps screen is not displayed

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin, google-fit

I am creating an Android application with Kotlin.
My app uses Google Fit API to get the number of steps.
Implemented the function to authenticate the scope according to the manual.

#### Problem

Unverified apps screen is not displayed
※Attach images of Google Cloud Platform and device for each condition.
The test was conducted under three types of conditions.

1. Test in production environment
   I got stuck when the "Unverified App" screen was displayed.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcXS3.jpg)
2. Test in a test environment　※Authenticate as a test user
   I was able to authenticate normally.
   ※Since you can authenticate here, I think that the scope setting and the creation of the  authentication information are successful.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wePPd.jpg)
3. Test in a test environment　※Authenticate as a non-test user
   I got stuck when the "Unverified App" screen was displayed.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG8N0.jpg)

#### Question

We would appreciate it if you could give us some information as to why the "Unverified App" screen is not displayed.
Please confirm.

#### Source

in my app AndroidManifest File

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="unity.yoububun.fitoathtest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.FitOathTest">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

in my app build.gradle File

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {･･･}

dependencies {
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0")

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

in my app MainActivity.kt File

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .build()
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)

        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this, // your activity
                10, // e.g. 1
                account,
                fitnessOptions)
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

#### Logcat

※ Play 1. Test in production environment

```
2021-09-04 18:35:52.531 1133-1133/? E/LOGD: logd_dispatch_uevent() failed
2021-09-04 18:35:52.538 12834-12862/? E/DetectMoisture: [onUEventForWireless] IOException
2021-09-04 18:35:52.542 12834-12862/? E/DetectMoisture: [onUEventForPadDetect] IOException
2021-09-04 18:35:52.899 32526-32526/? E/EmojiDrawable: stopCallbackDrawing parameter is failhandler = null
2021-09-04 18:35:53.188 14549-14549/? E/.android.chrom: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-09-04 18:35:53.209 16445-16818/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT. App: unity.yoububun.fitoathtest, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
2021-09-04 18:35:53.737 1101-10629/? E/ANDR-IOP: IIop:: Iop HAL Service is not available.
2021-09-04 18:35:53.746 14596-14596/? E/webview_servic: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-09-04 18:35:53.798 27735-29915/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-09-04 18:35:53.828 14617-14617/? E/m.android.emai: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-09-04 18:35:53.873 32526-32526/? E/EmojiDrawable: stopCallbackDrawing parameter is failhandler = null
2021-09-04 18:35:53.912 1101-10629/? E/ANDR-IOP: IIop:: Iop HAL Service is not available.
2021-09-04 18:35:54.014 16445-16818/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT. App: unity.yoububun.fitoathtest, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
2021-09-04 18:35:54.126 14663-14663/? E/ndroid.exchang: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
```

Comment: Please consult [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)  this is formated a little extream.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Fixed the format.

Comment: Did you find a solution to thids issue?

Comment: Have you figured out whhy this was happening?